# Android:Can I use adb command in my app?

Tags: android, command-line, adb

all
  here is my problem,I want to start an android TestProject in my app,but I don't konw how,and I found that I can start it with command ,e.g. "adb shell am instrument -w com.demo.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
  So I have tried use in my app :Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell am instrument -w com.demo.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner");but have:

03-15 02:24:42.246: WARN/System.err(3597): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [adb, shell, am, instrument, -w, com.demo.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner] Working Directory: null Environment: null
.....
03-15 02:24:42.246: WARN/System.err(3597): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
  where is my problem?

Comment: I don't know if I understand this correctly, so from inside your Android app you are attempting to run adb? I don't think that is the right way to do what you want.

Comment: yes,but is there a function to run another app such as a TestProject or a case in the TestProject? and thanks for your attention to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already an API for this,  [Context.startInstrumentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startInstrumentation%28android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

This is how the shell command is implemented.  You can't do anything more by launching a shell command than you can do in your own process.  Also, no shell commands are part of the SDK, so anything you do with it is likely to break at some point on different devices or versions of the platform.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Context.startInstrumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startInstrumentation%28android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29), instead of adb.
For example, from your Activity, run

```
startInstrumentation(new ComponentName("com.example.aatg.tc.test", "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"), null, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

Short answer - no.  Long answer, kinda.

The part after the 'adb shell' command is the part that is executed, much like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`

You may be able to achieve what you're after by using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("instrument -w com.demo.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner")`.  I've not used it myself, but you may need to pass the arguments in as an array.  Check [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Comment: I can use startInstrumentation() to what I want to achieve,and thanks for your advise.

Comment: it will not work in Android 4.2 onwards, "am instrument" only system app can call for Android 4.2

Comment: Good to know @VISHALVIRADIA.  Thanks for the clarification.  As I mentioned, this isn't a solution.  It's a nasty hack and should be treated with caution.